# Eclipse: Experiencing mysterious Package Explorer issues - Shows Projects as Versioned

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, versioning, egit, m2e

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 / Eclipse Indigo SR1 Build id: 20110916-0149

In the Package Explorer most of my Projects are located in the default Workspace.

Some projects, however, are imports from a /src directory I use whenever I import projects  clones from git, google, or sourceforge etcetera. '

In Eclipse those projects I import from the /src directory many times, but not always, show up with a preceding `*` and trailing `[master]`

Mysteriously, some of my own projects I imported after I upgraded my system and installed Indigo also have a preceding `*` and trailing `[master]`.

**Question:**

Anyone know what handles SVN/Mercurial/Git in Eclipse?

Are there settings to control this behavior (Either in Eclipse or on the OS filesystem side)?

List of possible plugins causing this problem: Eclipse EGit, M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse, and Aptana Studio 3

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am still not certain of the origin of this issue, I have found out how to disassociate it to the SVN/Git/Whatever it is attached to.

Right click project --> Team --> Disconnect

or highlighted project /w shortcut keys --> Shift + Alt + G Delete

If anyone has ideas on how my projects would have mysteriously have come to be synced I'd appreciate the insight.